# C: Reading from OpenSSL Socket

Tags: c, linux, ssl, networking, openssl

I'm using the OpenSSL library to secure network messages, but for some reason it doesn't always seems to work. Actually most of the time it doesn't work. When I run the compiled code and connect to the socket, most of the time it just runs the code of the main process in the child as well, but sometimes it runs the child instructions. Obiously, this isn't the way it should work, the child should exit instead, after it handled the client (`handle_client(newfd)`) all the time. One interesting part is, if I remove the `handle_client(newfd)` line from the child instructions and put something small there, like `printf("test")`, then the child works every time as it should, it prints test and exits right after that. Is this some kind of limitation in fork(), or I just shouldn't run this much code in a child? Or something else? Any help would be really appriciated!

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "json.h"
#include "create_socket.h"
#include "get_addr.h"
#include "handle_income.h"
#include "handle_client.h"
int main(void) {
  int newfd;
  struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
  char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  pid_t pid;
  unsigned int cpc = 0;
  int listenfd = create_socket("8069");
  if (listenfd < 0)
    exit(1);
  while(1) {
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    if ((newfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1)
      continue;
    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
      get_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
    printf("conn %s siz %d\n", s, (int) sin_size); //REMOVE
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
      exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
      close(listenfd);
      handle_client(newfd);
      exit(0);
    }
    printf("child %d\n", (int) pid); //REMOVE
    cpc++;
    while(cpc) {
      pid = waitpid((pid_t) -1, NULL, WNOHANG);
      if (pid < 0)
        exit(1);
      else if (pid == 0)
        break;
      else
        cpc--;
    }
  }
  EVP_cleanup();
  exit(0);
}
```

handle_client.h:

```
#define READ_SIZE 32
void handle_client(int newfd) {
  char *buffer = NULL;
  char *tmp_buffer = malloc(READ_SIZE);
  unsigned long buffer_size = 0;
  unsigned long received = 0;
  int status = 0;
  SSL_load_error_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
  SSL_CTX *sslctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
  if (sslctx) {
    SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(sslctx, 1);
    if ((SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslctx, "/ssl-cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) > 0) {
      if ((SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslctx, "/ssl-key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM)) > 0) {
        SSL *ssl = SSL_new(sslctx);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, newfd);
        if (SSL_accept(ssl) > 0) {
          fcntl(newfd, F_SETFL, fcntl(newfd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);
          do {
            if (received >= buffer_size) {
              char *tmp;
              buffer_size += READ_SIZE;
              if ((tmp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size)) == NULL) {
                break;
              } else {
                buffer = tmp;
              }
            }
            status = SSL_read(ssl, tmp_buffer, READ_SIZE);
            if (status > 0) {
              received += status;
              strncat(buffer, tmp_buffer, status);
            } else {
              ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            }
          } while (status > 0);
          free(tmp_buffer);
          buffer[received] = 0;
          if (received < buffer_size) {
            buffer = realloc(buffer, received);
          }
          printf("%s\n", buffer); //REMOVE
          char *response = handle_income(buffer);
          SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));
          printf("%s\n", response); //REMOVE
        }
        SSL_free(ssl);
      }
    }
  }
  SSL_CTX_free(sslctx);
  close(newfd);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear exactly what error you get. Please look at [mcve]

Comment: I knew i need to be minimalistic, but if i like replace handle_client(newfd) with printf("test") then the results won't be the same. What I'm trying to say is, most of this code is important to reproduce the error, but i will definitely remove the spare lines.

Comment: I was not saying to remove code but instead to add exactly what happens when you launch your software, what it does display...

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a proper error description. As a rule of thumb when you are stuck with something that "doesn't work", try to answer these distinct questions instead: What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? And why are you surprised this happened instead?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your requests, I was pretty tired that day. I've edited the question, hopefully it's understandable now.

Comment: handle_client() propbably overwrites the correct return address in the stack, if the exit(0) is not called after handle_client() call.

Comment: It's not just the exit(0) that isn't called, even if i put something before handle_client(), that won't be called, even handle_client() won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

There might be other problems too, but you should fix the following buffer overflow error, and check if it fix visible problem too:

`SSL_read` may return less than `READ_SIZE`. So the next piece of code is broken.
Problem occurs for example, when the 1st `SSL_read()` returns for example 16, and the next call return 32 (=READ_SIZE). Allocated `buffer` size during 2nd `strncat` call is 32, so buffer overflow may occurs during `strncat()`.

```
        if (received >= buffer_size) {
          char *tmp;
          buffer_size += READ_SIZE;
          if ((tmp = realloc(buffer, buffer_size)) == NULL) {
            break;
          } else {
            buffer = tmp;
          }
        }
        status = SSL_read(ssl, tmp_buffer, READ_SIZE);
        if (status > 0) {
          received += status;
          strncat(buffer, tmp_buffer, status);
        }
        ...
```

There might be other problem with `strncat` call. It needs one extra byte for null terminator of string. From man page:

> the size of dest must be at least strlen(dest)+n+1

Comment: I think i fixed it, but i can't test it, because the child still doesn't process what it should.